# How to properly offset will_paginate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, offset, will-paginate

I'm building my own forum software, and in the thread display I am paginating replies. It works well, except that I need to exclude the first post from pagination since it is rendered separately and differently.

I have tried a number of approaches, including:

- Putting "offset: 1" in the controller's paginate command, which works properly but produces the same post list for each page
- The first approach listed at [get will_paginate to define a custom offset on the first page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513519/get-will-paginate-to-define-a-custom-offset-on-the-first-page), which does not work in my case (I am paginating @discussion.posts instead of just @posts).

What's the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is just to check that if you are on Page 1

```
params[:page] == 1
```

And if so, then only render the collection of replies, except for the first.

```
@replies[1..-1].each do (reply)
  ..
```